# segue back with NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am in Viewcontroller B with its NavigationBar, button pressed in Viewcontroller B goes to Viewcontroller C (I don't want NavigationBar in Viewcontroller C)

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewC") as! ViewcontrollerC
    vc.passAction = "saveedit"
    vc.passName = passName
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I click save Button in ViewcontrollerC I should go back to ViewcontrollerB with ViewcontrollerB NavigationBar

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewB") as! ViewcontrollerB
            vc.passName = "\(firstNameTxt.text!)\(" ")\(lastNameTxt.text!)"
             self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Here the problem is When I go back to ViewcontrollerB I don't see NavigationBar there.

**EDITED**

```
class ViewcontrollerB : UpdateDataDelegate {

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }


@IBAction func click_edit(_ sender: Any) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "patientPersonalData") as! patientPersonalDataVC
    vc.passName = passName
    vc.passAction = "saveedit"

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

  }  

func loadData() {

}
}
```

//ViewcontrollerC

```
protocol UpdateDataDelegate {
    func loadData()
}
 class Viewcontroller C {
 var delegate: UpdateDataDelegate?

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

fun click_save() {
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
 self.delegate?.loadData()
}
```

}

Comment: are you embed your viewcontroller with navigation controller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes, In storyboard its connection with navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you create a new ViewcontrollerB.
Try this to go back to ViewcontrollerB.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply dismiss `ViewcontrollerC` on pressing `Save` button?

In `ViewcontrollerC`:

```
var closure: ((String)->())? //Set this closure when you present ViewcontrollerC from ViewcontrollerB

func save()
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {[weak self] in
        self?.closure?("Your_Data")
    }
}
```

This will move you back to `ViewControllerB` where the `navigation bar` is already present.

You don't need to hide/show the `navigation bar` anywhere, neither while presenting `ViewControllerC`, nor when dismissing it.

Comment: But here you can't send the data to previous controller. I want to send the new data which I added in ViewcontrollerC to ViewcontrollerB.

Comment: You can use a closure for that purpose and call that closure in completion of dismiss method.

Comment: check my edited question. Where am I going wrong with delegate I don't understand

Comment: I don't understand your code what are you trying to do. And please don't ask same question again and again. I have already answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479936/5716829

Answer (score 0):

Try to present it using navigation controller

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewC") as! ViewcontrollerC
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

and add the following line in your ViewcontrollerC's viewWillAppear method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

when leave from ViewcontrollerC's viewWillDisAppear method.

```
override func viewWillDisAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillDisAppear(animated)
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have posted code dedicated on UINavigationBar appearance management on github. check out [RRViewControllerExtension](https://github.com/Roen-Ro/RRViewControllerExtension), it will solve your problem gracefully.
with RRViewControllerExtension all you have to do is just override method in your viewcontroller.

```
//override any of the methods below in your viewcontroller's .m file to make specific navigation bar appearance

-(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden;
-(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarTransparent;

-(nullable UIColor *)preferredNavatationBarColor;
-(nullable UIColor *)preferredNavigationItemColor;
-(nullable UIImage *)preferredNavigationBarBackgroundImage;
-(nullable NSDictionary *)preferredNavigationTitleTextAttributes;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this .. unhide navigationBar in viewWillAppear of viewControllerC and hide it in viewWillAppear of viewControllerB .

```
//ViewController C
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

//ViewController B
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated);
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

try this then

```
//ViewController C
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
 self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

//ViewController B
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```